# Dealing Cards game: x cards per y over z Amount of Players Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've been trying to come up with an algorithm which deals, as the title states,
X amount of Cards, per Y amount of Cards, over Z amount of Players of a normal (52 piece) Deck of Cards which is sorted or unsorted. I've been walking into a wall for the past few hours to come up with a working solution, while also Googling to find similar problems. Unfortunately without success, hence this question.

An example would be: dealing 2 Cards, per 1, over 2 Players would result in

1. Player 1 receiving 1 card
2. Player 2 receiving 1 card
3. Player 1 receiving 1 card
4. Player 2 receiving 1 card

Until now I have a solution with which I'm able to run my application, although the actual dealing algorithm isn't keeping the 'per' parameter into account. It will deal the right amount of cards to the Y amount of players, although each player will receive the total amount to be dealed in 1 go..

I was wondering if anyone here had to handle a similar problem in the past? Or could guide me into the right direction? :/

```
public List<Card>[] Deel(int per, int players, int cards)
    {
        _currentCard= 0;
        List<Card>[] output = new List<Card>[players];
        if (_cardsDistributed < _deck.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
            {
                List<Card> hand = new List<Card>();
                for (int j = 0; j < cards; j++)
                {
                    _currentCard= 0;
                    hand.Add(_deck[_currentCard]);
                    _deck.Remove(_deck[_currentCard]);
                    _cardsDistributed++;
                }
                output[i] = hand;

            }
            return output;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: 'per' here is 'at a time'? so if it was per 2 i would deal 2 cards to player 1, then 2 cards to player 2... potentially looping back around?

Comment: Hi @tolanj , per is meant as 'at a time' indeed. The problem there is when a player has to be dealt eg. 5 cards, 2 at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this is to get a deck of cards and do it yourself, by hand, and write down the steps. For example, you have three players and you want to deal each player four cards, two at a time. So what do you do?

You take the deck in hand, hold it over the first player's pile, and deal two cards. The code for that is pretty simple:

```
player = 1
for i = 1 to 2
    deal next card to player
```

Then you move to the second player's pile and deal two cards, and you do the same thing for the third player. So you need a loop to go through the players:

```
for player = 1 to 3
    for i = 1 to 2
        deal next card to player
```

At this point you've dealt two cards to each of the three players.

If you want to deal X cards Y at a time, and Y is smaller than X, then you need to go around to each player multiple times. How many? Well, how many times does Y go into X? The answer is X/Y.

If you were doing this by hand, you would start over at player 1, deal him two cards, move on to player 2, etc. Adding that in code is simple:

```
numRounds = 4/2
for round = 1 to numRounds
    for player = 1 to 3
        for card = 1 to 2
            deal next card to player
```

Now, replace the constant values with X, Y, and Z, and try it with some other combination by following those exact steps. Deal six cards to each player, three at a time. Did it work? Try a few other combinations to verify that the steps you wrote down always work.

Once you've determined that the algorithm you've developed works, then writing the code to implement it on the computer is easy. There are, of course, some minor details like how to deal a card, but those are easy compared to figuring out the overall approach to the problem.

I was fortunate that I discovered this approach to problem solving early in my education. Casting an algorithmic problem into physical terms lets me build a model that I can play with, and write down the steps I took to solve the problem. After that, writing the program is a simple matter of duplicating those steps in code. It doesn't work for *all* problems, but it's very effective for a large number of different problems that you will encounter.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the extensive answer! I'm usually quite good at working out these algorithms, but for this one I always tried using a structure of loops where players > cards > 'at a time' , which obviously made me run into a wall every single time. I'll definitely keep your tips in mind in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you need something like this:

```
public List<Card>[] Deel(int per, int players, int cards)
{
    List<Card>[] output = new List<Card>[players];

    // init hand for each player
    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
    {
        output[i] = new List<Card>();
    }

    // assume the number of cards is divided by 'per' without a remainder
    // otherwise you need one more round to deal rest (cards % per) cards
    int rounds = cards / per;

    for (int round = 0; round < rounds; round++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < per; j++)
            {
                if (_deck.Count > 0)
                {
                    output[i].Add(_deck[0]);
                    _deck.Remove(_deck[0]);

                    _cardsDistributed++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // should throw an exception because the deck contains no more cards
                    // or maybe you need to check it before dealing
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the answer! As I see I've been very close to this version as well, although I think I dropped it somewhere along the way (read "frustration"). The problem with this though is when a player has to be dealt eg. 5 cards, 2 at a time. For now I solved this by adding a 'extraCard' boolean with if(card % per != 0) and creating a smaller loop which adds 1 card to each player's List of cards. This works although I'm not entirely convinced this is the best way to solve this issue.